Is there a way to keep track of faces while modifying a triangulation with CGAL
In CGAL, we have face handles to access the faces of a Delaunay triangulation. But those face handles are invalidated, as far as I understand, as soon as any modification is done to the triangulation, see Lifecycle for CGAL vertex handles?.
In Chew refinement algorithm, a list of faces to optimize is constructed, and a point is inserted at the circumcenter of the worst face. However, because all the handles are invalidated once the point is added, the list of face to optimize must be reconstructed from scratch.
This is a costly operation. It would be better to be able to keep track of the unmodified faces, discard the faces which are not valid anymore, and check only the new faces created by the Delaunay insertion.
I tried to directly access the face range in the triangulation data structure, and to store the index of the face in the face range, as well as some other data to check the face is still the same as before. But then I have a problem: I need to know the index of a face handle in the face range container. I tried using:
std::size_t index = std::distance(face_range.begin(), face_handle);

And it didn't work, as I feared:
CGAL ERROR: assertion violation!
Expr: DSC::type(m_ptr) != DSC::START_END
File: /usr/include/CGAL/Compact_container.h
Line: 968

I thus have several questions:

Do a face in the face range keep the same index when new faces are added ?
Is it possible to obtain the index of a Face_handle (which is an iterator) in the face range ?
Is there a way to do what I want to do (keeping track of faces after modifying the triangulation) which I am not aware of ?

Edit: I tired using
std::size_t index = face_range.index(face_handle)

But it returns a stupidly large number.

Why not simply collecting the faces incident to each vertex inserted during the refinement?

This does not change anything. When adding a point in the circumcenter of the worst triangle, I still loose all the face handles of the the previous triangles in the list I constructed.

Well your list will still feature valid face handles (as long as you don't remove any point). You simply need to test that your criteria is still valid (in case the original face was invalidated during insertion).

I made this hypothesis, but later during the refinement when I add a node on a constrained edge either CGAL produces a flat triangle or I have an assertion violation when I try to remove the constrained edge. It does not seem to work, so my 3 questions.

Faces are stored in the Compact_container that has the property to reuse faces that have been removed. It means that if the total number of faces does not decrease all the handles will still refer to a face that is used in the triangulation. Your problem must be somewhere else. Providing a minimal example showing the issue would be helpful IMHO.

Indeed when I only add points, the Face_handles seem to remain valid, which is great. When I remove points, I have to assume that all Face_handles are not valid anymore ?

Not all of them. There is a free list where delete face handles are put in. I think you can use the is_used() method to check that, on the container returned by the method faces().
